# Wordpress custom pagination with pretty URL's

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently having slight issues with WP pagination. I've developed a custom theme which requires paging. The paging query is below:

```
<?php if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination   ?>
                            <?php

                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                    'format' => 'page/%#%',
                                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('page')),
                                    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                                    'prev_text' => __('«'),
                                    'next_text' => __('»'),
                                    'mid_size' => 3
                            ));
                            ?>
```

Now the paging actually works perfectly if I leave it to the default URL structure of `?page=$page_num` however as you can see from the above we are attempting to utilize a slightly prettier URL structure which should have paging set out like `/page/$page_num`. I have attempted the following `.htaccess` rewrite however I am still returned a 404 page when navigating to `/page/$page_num` yet `?page=$page_num` still works fine.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /blog/?page=$1 [L,R=301] 

</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

I am at a total loss of the next steps to take. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog/?page=$1 [L]
```